# how would i pass the element as a parameter through the nested function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-structures, prototype

I'm trying to pass the selector as a parameter through the `Slider` to an Object nested function.

I expected that `istouchEnd` could get the `.storage1` as a parameter form the `Slider` but `this.storage` never receives the parameter from the `Slider` function.

Is there any ways to pass(or get whatever) the `span` tag through the `Slider` function as a parameter?

```js
'use strict';

const blueMethods = {
  count: 1,
  istouchStart(e) {
    this.coordX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    return this.coordX;
  },
  istouchMove(e) {
    let drag = e.touches[0].clientX;
    let dist = Math.sqrt(drag + this.coordX);
  },
  istouchEnd(e) {
    let dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX; 
    $(this.storage).text(dist);
  }
}
function Slider(target, storage) {
  Slider.target = target;
  Slider.storage = storage;
  $(Slider.target).stop(true, true).on({
  touchstart:blueMethods.istouchStart, 
  touchmove:blueMethods.istouchMove,
  touchend:blueMethods.istouchEnd
  });
};

const box1 = Slider('.page1', '.storage1');
box1;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.page1 {
  width: 48vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.page2 {
  width: 48vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="page1"></div>
  <div class="page2"></div>
</div>
<div class="textbox">
  <span class="storage1"></span>
  <span class="storage2" data-count></span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is purpose of this `box1;` on last line?

Comment: @MaheerAli it's for executing the `const box1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set event handlers which are methods in some object and want to pass some parameters and also give them acces `this` you can create handlers in following way - e.g.  for function `istouchEnd`

```
  istouchEnd(storage) {
    return (e) => {
      let dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX; 
      $(storage).text(dist);
    }
  }
```

As you see the `istouchEnd` is not handler, but it create and return handler (using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) which has access to `this.coordX` and storage parameter. You use it by change `touchend:blueMethods.istouchEnd` to

```
touchend:blueMethods.istouchEnd(storage)
```

```js
'use strict';
const blueMethods = {
  count: 1,
  istouchStart() {
    return (e) => {
      this.coordX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      return this.coordX;
    }
  },
  istouchMove() {
    return (e) => {
      let drag = e.touches[0].clientX;
      let dist = Math.sqrt(drag + this.coordX);
    }
  },
  istouchEnd(storage) {
    return (e) => {
      let dist = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.coordX; 
      $(storage).text(dist);
    }
  }
}
function Slider(target, storage) {
  Slider.target = target;
  Slider.storage = storage;
  $(Slider.target).stop(true, true).on({
  touchstart:blueMethods.istouchStart(), 
  touchmove:blueMethods.istouchMove(),
  touchend:blueMethods.istouchEnd(storage)
  });
};

const box1 = Slider('.page1', '.storage1');
box1;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.page1 {
  width: 48vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.page2 {
  width: 48vw;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="page1"></div>
  <div class="page2"></div>
</div>
<div class="textbox">
  <span class="storage1"></span>
  <span class="storage2" data-count></span>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This problem was frustrated me. Thank you for answering :>

Comment: @l3lue I update answer and change other methods (and touchstart and touchmove binding) too to give them acces to object properties like this.coordX